# How to split a series into two other series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do you take this $$\sum_{n=0}^{100} \frac{1}{a^n+b^n}\:\;\text{(or)}\:\;\sum_{n=0}^{100} \frac{x}{a^n+b^n}$$ and split it into two sums, one having only $1$ (or $x$) and $a$ and the other having only $1$ (or $x$) and $b$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible. Let
$$f(a,b)=\sum_{n=0}^{100}\frac{1}{a^n+b^n}.$$
We have that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}=-\sum_{n=0}^{100}\frac{n b^{n-1}}{(a^n+b^n)^2}$$
which clearly depends on $a$. If we were to have
$$f(a,b)=g(a)+k(b)$$
then we'd have that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}=k'(b)$$
doesn't depend on $a$.

Comment: +1 you got there first. Welcome to stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If that sum were of the form $f(a) + g(b)$ then the partial derivative with respect to $a$ would be independent of $b$. That's clearly not the case.

Comment: Ok but what about $$\sum_{n=0}^{100} {-1}^{n-1}*{3an+2bn}$$ How would you split this

Comment: @James That one is easy.  It's just the distributive law. Write out the sum with ellipses or for an upper limit of $2$ instead of $100$ without the $\Sigma$.